# Visual Studio code Debugging Node.JS NOENT: no such file or directory when debugging with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-code

have a very strange problem. I'm coding a few small **Node.JS** programs, and debugging them in Visual Studio Code (for Windows). Well, recently I started to get a weird issue when the program hits the line:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
```

no matter what program I use. Actually it doesn't even has to be a complete program. If my file contains only that line, it will fail with the same issue.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing NPM, MongoDB, and also the packages for my solution and nothing works.

Now the weirdest thing is the program works fine when i run it on the command line. It only fails on the Visual Studio Code debugger.

It appears somewhere in the internal libraries to load modules, this path is generated:

```
[program_location]\node_modules\require_optional<b>\index.js\package.json
```

which of course doesn't exist an fails because it won't ever find this file (since is not a valid file anyway)

**here's the trace:**

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'c:\NodeJS\Module03\MongoMigration\node_modules\require_optional\index.js\package.json'
>       at fs.existsSync (fs.js:329:13)
>       at find_package_json (c:\NodeJS\Module03\MongoMigration\node_modules\require_optional\index.js:14:9)
>       at find_package_json_with_name (c:\NodeJS\Module03\MongoMigration\node_modules\require_optional\index.js:34:20)
>       at require_optional (c:\NodeJS\Module03\MongoMigration\node_modules\require_optional\index.js:69:13)
>       at Object. (c:\NodeJS\Module03\MongoMigration\node_modules\mongodb-core\index.js:8:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)

It must be something wrongly configured on my machine. Just trying to find if there is somebody who has resolved this one or has some ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I was having the issue today. I found that you can fix it if you disable break on "All Exceptions"

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it... not sure when I checked that option, but I can now run it without issues.

Thanks a lot!!

(I would vote this up, but I cannot yet)

Comment: @McFloyd You should accept his answer than. It fixed it for me as well.